# When to use ExponentialBackOffPolicy vs FixedBackOffPolicy when setting retry policy for a kafka consumer in a Spring boot app?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When to use ExponentialBackOffPolicy vs FixedBackOffPolicy when setting retry policy for a kafka consumer in a Spring boot app?

I see **FixedBackOffPolicy** as an implementation of BackOffPolicy that pauses for a fixed period of time before continuing and **ExponentialBackOffPolicy** as an implementation of BackOffPolicy that increases the back off period for each retry attempt in a given set.

Apart from this, FixedBackOffPolicy extends StatelessBackOffPolicy whereas ExponentialBackOffPolicy don't. In this aspect, Please help me understand, what are the appropriate use cases to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward; `FixedBackOffPolicy` needs no state because you wait for the same interval between each retry, e.g. 5 seconds.

E.g. 5s, 5s, 5s, ...

With the `ExponentialBackOffPolicy` state is maintained between retries.

E.g. with an initial interval of 1s, a multiplier of 2.0 and max interval of 10s the retry intervals will be 1s, 2s, 4s, 8s, 10s, 10s, 10s, ...

With Kafka you need to be sure that the aggregate of the retry intervals is less than `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: Thanks for the details.

Comment: I don't have permissions to vote but I can accept the answer and did it. Thanks

Comment: i've a question here. with these settings, what happens if the 'session.timeout.ms' was set to less than 10s (let's say 9s)? would it trigger a re-balance before retrying?

Comment: Session timeout is no longer important (see KIP-62); the important one is `max.poll.interval.ms` which defaults to 5 minutes; if you suspend longer than that, Kafka will perform a rebalance. You can deal with that (with recent versions) using a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` which now has built in retry and backoff - the exception is thrown to the container after each failure so Kafka is happy.

Comment: Does it mean, if we have both 'session.timeout.ms' and max.poll.interval.ms values set, would it consider only 'max.poll.interval.ms' to trigger a rebalance ?

Comment: Yes; read [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) to understand the difference between those properties.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.